# Error while trying to upload a .bsq file to the geoserver

Tags: geoserver, file-formats, envi

I am trying to upload a .bsq file (ENVIHdr Coverage Format) to the geoserver. While doing this I got an error message. I am using the "GDAL" Extension for the geoserver. The error message is: "Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Incorrect input type!"  
Do I use the wrong extension or is there an other mechanism to upload a .bsq file to the geoserver ? After the upload I want to publish this raster data as a WCS service.

Comment: no ideas... ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Currently, the geoserver does not support ENVI .bsq files. You only can use ENVI .bil files. So, I decided to convert the ENVI .bsq file into a ESRI .bsq file. The geoserver can handle this. I used "gdal" for the conversion. I hope this helps.